# CakePHP Fixtures with JSON data

Tags: json, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, fixtures

I'm using the latest CakePHP version and want to do some PHPunit tests with fixtures. My MariaDB version doesn't support the JSON datatype, so I'm using the TEXT datatype for the table columns which should store json data. So for instance I have a table called *Items* with a column *json_options*. I've included CakePHP's predefined custom JSON datatype into my table model:

```
// in src/Model/Table/ItemsTable.php

protected function _initializeSchema(TableSchema $schema)
{
    $schema->columnType('json_column', 'json');
    return $schema;
}
```

Now I'm generating Fixtures with the Bake console and import some records from the table:

```
 bake fixture items -c fixture -r
```

The (simplified) result is something like this:

```
// in /tests/Fixture/ItemsFixture.php

public $fields = [
    'id' => ['type' => 'integer', 'length' => 10, 'unsigned' => true, 'null' => false, 'default' => null, 'comment' => '', 'autoIncrement' => true, 'precision' => null],
    'json_options' => ['type' => 'text', 'length' => null, 'null' => true, 'default' => null, 'collate' => 'utf8_general_ci', 'comment' => '', 'precision' => null],

public $records = [
    'id' => 1
    'options' => array(
        'someKey' => 'someValue'
    )    
]
```

The problem now is: The *json_options* column has the type **text** in the $fields-definition, but the record holds an array and not a string. This leads to an exception when running tests:

```
Exception: Cannot convert value to string in src\Database\Type\StringType.php
```

If I change the type from **text** to **json**, the tests are working. But it is a lot of work to change the type manually in all table fixtures after every import of records.

So is there any possibility that the Bake shell detects the json column during Fixture generation and use the correct type? Or is there a way to change the schema definition in the Fixture on the fly for example in the ItemsControllerTest.php's setUp() method? Or any other hint how to handle json data in Fixtures?

Answer (score 0):

Simply override the constructor of the fixture:

```
/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function __constructor() {
    parent::__construct();

    foreach ($this->records as &$record) {
        $record['data'] = json_encode($record['data']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is not working for me because on every fixture generation with the Bake command, the overridden constructor will be overwritten and I have to insert it manually again.

Comment: Overriden??? You bake your fixtures again before each test run or what!? This works fine as this is exactly what we do with JSON data in our fixtures.

Comment: No I don't bake it each time, but I don't bake it only once. The test data could change during development, so it would be nice to have an easy way to generate fixtures from the changed test data. If I have to edit each fixture manually, it is easier to just change the type from "text" to "json" in the $fields-property.